# Display logo twice in Material design menu

Tags: usability, website-design, navigation, user-expectation, material-design

Is it a bad design to have a logo twice in Material Design menu, One with collapsible mode and the one when the menu is expanded as below?

[image]

Since I make the logo two places here, our marketing team need to see the logo on default view and when the menu is open (expanded).

This is an intranet website, all the franchises and branches are using this website.

if this is not a good UX practice I would be able to convince the marketing team to remove the logo from one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, the logo section should be consistent and fixed. In my opinion, if you hide the logo with a new sidebar which overlaps it, it will not look good. What I can suggest is to try keeping the logo part fixed and toggle the rest of the sidebar section. And provide a close icon or button which toggles the sidebar:

[image]